# Evaluating $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{3x} \left(5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{3x} \left(5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt$$

The answer I come up with is:  $5\sin(3x)(3)-7e^{4(3x)}(3)$, however this was not on the answer choice. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{3x} \left(5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{3x}\left( 5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt-\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_0^{1}\left(5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{3x}\left( 5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt+0\\
&=\left( 5\sin (3x)-7e^{4\cdot3x}+1\right)\cdot3\\
&=15\sin (3x)-21e^{12x}+3\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{3x} \left(5\sin (t)-7e^{4t}+1\right)\,\mathrm dt=15\sin (3x)-21e^{12x}+3$$

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{3x}\left(5\sin{t}-7e^{4t}+1\right)dt=15\sin{3x}-21e^{12x}+3$$

use this
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt=f(u(x))\cdot u'(x)-f(v(x))\cdot v'(x)$$

Comment: +1 thanks! how does the last term become $3$?

Comment: Hello,use  $(3x)'=3$

Comment: Don't you have $u$ and $v$ reversed in your general formula?